# C++ Concepts: How to use 'concept' to check the property of a templated struct?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm currently experimenting with the new c++2a 'concepts' feature. The goal of my code below is to check some property of a templated struct. As the first template argument [is 'reserved' for the type to be checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973364/c-partial-concept-id-what-is-the-reason-for-the-explicit-template-specificati), I have difficulties using the concept without a `requires` expression or specifying template arguments manually. This is not a big deal, but I like the `concept` notation for its clarity. Is there a way to work around this?

## Compiler

```sh
gcc-g++-10.0 (GCC) 10.0.1 20200119 (experimental)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

## Compile command

```sh
g++-10.0 -std=c++2a file.cc
```

## Code

```cpp
#include <concepts>

/// Struct has template arguments and a property that can be checked in a concept.
template <bool a> struct A {
  constexpr static bool property() noexcept { return a; }
};

template <typename T, bool a> concept hasProp = std::is_same_v<T, A<a>> && A<a>::property();

template <bool a> requires hasProp<A<a>, a> void works(A<a> c) {} 
template <bool a, hasProp<a> c> void deductionError(c d) {};

// This is a sketch of what I'd like to do:
// template <A<a, b> Class, bool a, bool b> concept hasProp = Class::property;

int main() {
  A<true> a;
  A<false> b;

  works(a);
  //works(b); //doesn't compile as the constraint is not fulfilled, which is desired.

  //deductionError(a); // I get why this deduction error occurs, but is it possible to do this
                      // in a clean way using concepts without having so specify template arguments?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial class template specializations to the rescue:

```
template<class T> 
struct HasProp : std::false_type{};

template<bool a>
struct HasProp<A<a>> : std::integral_constant<bool, A<a>::property()>
{};

template <class T> 
concept hasProp = HasProp<T>::value;

template <bool a> 
requires hasProp<A<a>>
void works(A<a>) {}

template<hasProp C> 
void deductionError(C){} // no longer a deductionError
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QK1TWTBFfBdCGPbc)

---

This does (perhaps needlessly) tie your concept to `A` directly.

You could instead do this (Like [@Barry answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378297/27678)):

```
template <class T> 
concept hasProp = T::property();
```

[Demo2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G11g2o0clvKm4smi)

Comment: That's actually a pretty cool trick :)  thanks for your answer!

Comment: @mutableVoid: Glad to help. I'm still pretty new to concepts myself (aren't we all?) so I don't know if this is an optimal implementation. One thing I did want to point out is my use of `std::conjunction` instead of `&&`. When you use `&&` in a metaprogramming context, there is no short-circuit evaluation, so both sides are always evaluated. `std::conjunction` gives  us the short-circuit evaluation that we want.

Comment: That's cool I didn't know that either and I think that might actually also be an answer to a question I just had in mind :) (I just started trying to make a conjunction of a set of concepts via a parameter pack)

Comment: You're basically specializing `HasProp` on `A<a>`... but you're doing it in a very roundabout way. Just do `HasProp<A<a>> : integral_constant<bool, A<a>::property()> { };`

Comment: @Barry: That's true. I foolishly kept most of what OP already had without consideration. Will update.

Comment: @AndyG I just tried out the Solution by Barry, and I think that also `&&` and `||` performs 'short circuit evaluation', as `template <typename T> concept hasProp = true || (is_A<T>::value && T::property());` does not complain even if I use `deductionError` with an `int`, maybe this is different when used in concepts (or my compiler does this even though it's technically not required)?

Comment: @mutableVoid: The writers of the standard were smart to make short-circuit evaluation standard for constraint evaluation (concepts). In other meta-programming contexts this is not the case. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pJ9sRmsqBo3XOdvg)

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need the tie-in to `A`?

```
template <typename T> concept hasProp = T::property();

template <bool a> requires hasProp<A<a>> void works(A<a>); // ok
template <hasProp C> void deductionError(C);               // also ok
```

If you do need the tie-in, you can add that entirely local to `hasProp`:

```
// unfortunately this is hard to generalize due to the non-type template parameter
template <typename T> struct is_A : std::false_type { };
template <bool b> struct is_A<A<b>> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T> concept hasProp = is_A<T>::value && T::property();

// ... and the rest works as before
template <bool a> requires hasProp<A<a>> void works(A<a>); // ok
template <hasProp C> void deductionError(C);               // also ok
```

Either way, `hasProp` should just take a type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I think in the application I really make use of the concept, it might be better to explicitly make sure that the type of the template equals the type represented by 'A<bool>' in the example code above. But that's very interesting input for me, thanks for the suggestion! I also like the way the concept is partitioned in the part your answer into 'type-checking' and the property and will change that in my code :)

Comment: Unfortunately, usage of concept `hasProp` results in a hard-error when `T` has a static member-function named `property` that isn't marked `constexpr`. Wouldn't it be more versatile/robust to wrap the expression `T::property()` inside a `std::bool_constant`?